# Python: Merge sort

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x

How can I improve this code?

```
#import sys
#sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

def get_input():
    input_str = input("Enter elements to be sorted: ")
    try:
        lst = list(map(int, input_str.split()))
    except:
        raise TypeError("Please enter a list of integers only, seperated by a space!!")
    return lst

def merge(thelist, start_idx, mid_idx, last_idx):
    size_left = mid_idx - start_idx + 1
    size_right = last_idx - mid_idx

    left_lst = []
    right_lst = []

    for i in range(size_left):
        left_lst.append(thelist[start_idx + i])

    for j in range(size_right):
        right_lst.append(thelist[mid_idx + 1 + j])

    left_idx = 0
    right_idx = 0
    curr_idx = start_idx

    while left_idx < size_left and right_idx < size_right:
        if left_lst[left_idx] <= right_lst[right_idx]:
            thelist[curr_idx] = left_lst[left_idx]
            left_idx += 1

        else:
            thelist[curr_idx] = right_lst[right_idx]
            right_idx += 1

        curr_idx += 1

    while left_idx < size_left:
        thelist[curr_idx] = left_lst[left_idx]
        curr_idx += 1
        left_idx += 1

    while right_idx < size_right:
        thelist[curr_idx] = right_lst[right_idx]
        curr_idx += 1
        right_idx += 1

def merge_sort(thelist, start_idx, last_idx):
    if len(thelist) == 0:
        print("Empty list!!")

    elif len(thelist) == 1:
        print("Only one element!!")

    elif start_idx < last_idx:
        mid_idx = int((start_idx + last_idx) / 2)
        merge_sort(thelist, start_idx, mid_idx)
        merge_sort(thelist, mid_idx + 1, last_idx)
        merge(thelist, start_idx, mid_idx, last_idx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list = get_input()
    merge_sort(input_list, 0, len(input_list) - 1)
    print(*input_list, sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adhere to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) (Python Enhancement Proposal (PEP) 8) (there is tool support for this):

Comment your code properly.
Document your code properly.
In the code, using *docstring*s, making the documentation accessible to IDEs and introspection.

The first thing to document would be the interface of `merge_sort()`:
it may be of interest that it does not return something useful, but modifies `thelist`.
I think `start_idx` and `last_idx` should have default values. While I don't see how to specify something like `last_idx=len(thelist)` correctly, Python uses index -1 for *last element* - you'd need to document `last_idx` to be inclusive (as the name suggests, anyway). (Python commonly uses right index *exclusive*.) An alternative would be to use `None` for *to the end*.
Better get rid of printing in a function of general use than document it does so for specific input.

Having `merge()` work in-place, too, causes avoidable "copies" - allocate *one* buffer in ("top-level") merge_sort and "merge to and fro'".

Python has a built-in for *selecting a range of items in a sequence object*: [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings) - do not use loops for this.

You can denote `int(x / 2)` as `(x // 2)`.

Comment: (I'm reluctant to present code as there are too many things I've seen done more to my liking or would to much differently myself.)